# Recursive/no-parent wget doesn't follow links with cookie-based authentication

Tags: wget

I'm running `wget --recursive --no-parent --adjust-extension --convert-links --page-requisites --restrict-file-names=windows --keep-session-cookies --load-cookies cookies.txt  http://DOMAIN/private/` and it correctly downloads the `private/index.html` file.

I inspected this file and it is the correct page shown only with successful authentication. It contains markup like:

```
<ul><li><a class="CP___PAGEID_56400" href="http://DOMAIN/private/page1.html">My private page</a></li>...
```

However, after fetching all the resources (images etc.) it seems to think it's finished and shuts down after 'converting links'.

If I skip `--no-parent` it keeps going. So is the --no-parent flag somehow confusing wget as to subpages?

Answer (score 0):

Finally realized that wget is obeying **robots.txt**! I changed my command to `wget -e robots=off --wait 0.25 --recursive --no-parent ...` and got it working. I added the *--wait 0.25*  since I didn't want to clobber the server either.